# wordpress file execution order

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site which I manage(I am not a developer)
I ran a pagespeed test via [https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.texasarrestwarrants.org%2F&tab=mobile)
I got some issues like caching problems and so on so I used several plugins to take care of them.
however Im now stuck with Optimize CSS Delivery problems. 
so I thought to try and fix it by myself and move the problematic URLs to the end of the page, however I cant figure out where these URLS are coming from. or which page is requesting for them.

appreciate any help with this

Comment: We don't know where some files on your wesbite come from either.

Comment: thats very helpful.

Comment: Well, what did you expect? We have no access to your website and we don't know what css files you're talking about. But just open developer tools in your browser, go to network tab and select only css. You'll see paths of files, then depending on it, you'll see if it's from a theme or a plugin. You can go from there. Thing is though, CSS is supposed to be in the begging of the page, not end (that's for JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do in similiar situations: put some text inside the HTML elements of any php-file. E.g. put in page.php the "page-top" somewhere in the beginning of the file, put "page-end" at the end. In footer.php etc do the same. So you come very fast to the corner where the URLs might come from.

Comment: just echo "start"; inside the PHP?

Comment: if you look for example inside a typical "page.php" you could write:
    <div id="main-grid" class="row">
       STARTED ROW
          <div id="primary" class="content-area col-md-8">
      <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
       <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
       STARTED LOOP
    ...